# Will winterbash2013.stackexchange.com remain live after Winter Bash ends?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

I know that the hats are going to "go back into their boxes" and we won't be able to wear them anymore once Winter Bash is over. But will we still be able to log into the winterbash2013.stackexchange.com site and see our collection of hats? It would be nice to look back on our collections in the future!

Comment: Nostalgia for collections of fake hats for fake internet points?

Comment: @Tim Preeeetty much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The site will be up for a very short time after the event ends, but our plan is to take it down, like last year, and have it redirect to our promotions archive. There, you'll be able to access screenshots that capture the spirit of the event, but if there's something in particular you're interested in referencing forever, take screenshots yourself before the event ends.

Comment: What about the data? Will you create a public dump we can download?

Comment: Aww, sad. Good to know though, thanks! It'd be kinda fun to have a winter bash "profile" so you could forever share these hats with people :)

Comment: @WendiKidd Alas, the holiday cheer is ephemeral, and the elves in our servers will be migrating south for the winter...

Answer (score 2):

If 2012 is anything to go by, sadly not  - all we get is this teasing [remnant here](https://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash).

I would give up a minor appendage or two to don my `And I feel fine` hat just one more time ...